# How to delete all user inputs except one command in specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was working on a discord bot and for a verification channel. I want users to type only the `/verify` command: every message or command except `/verify` they type should get deleted automatically. How can I do this?
Current code:

```
if (command === "verify") {
  if (message.channel.id !== "ChannelID") return;
  let role = message.guild.roles.find(rol => rol.name === 'Member')

  const reactmessage = await message.channel.send('React with  to verify yourself!');
  await reactmessage.react('');
  const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;
  const collector = reactmessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
    time: 15000
  });
  collector.on('collect', async reaction => {
    const user = reaction.users.last();
    const guild = reaction.message.guild;
    const member = guild.member(user) || await guild.fetchMember(user);

    member.addRole(role);
    message.channel.send(`Verification Complete.. ${member.displayName}. You have got access to server. `)

  });
  message.delete();
}
```

Comment: did you tried any thing? please post them as well

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check at the top of your `client.on('message')` listener:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  let verified = !!message.member.roles.find(role => role.name == 'Member');
  // ... command parsing ect...
  if (!verified && command == 'verify') {...}
  else if (verified) {
    // other commands...
  }
});
```

Comment: Hii @Federico  thanks again for the reply. But when they don't have member role, they can't even run /verify. Also I want this system for one guild only.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I've edited my answer

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Comment: Hey @Federico Can you please check this because I can't post as a question because a question already answered is blocking it and that's not question or answer I want .https://hastebin.com/zuqiciwoku.coffeescript Thanks ^

Comment: Use `args.join(" ").split(" or ")`. Next time ask a new question ;) @DragieBRO